# How to capture CAAnimation

Tags: swift, calayer

I want to capture each frame of the animation on `CALayer` to generate `mp4` movie file.

So, I wrote codes below.

`frames` is total frame number in the animation, `frameTime` is 1 / 60 second, and `animationLayer` has already been added on `UIImageView`.

```
for i in 0...(frames - 1) {

    //add the animation on specified frame to the CALayer
    animationGroup.speed = 0
    animationGroup.timeOffset = frameTime * i
    animationLayer.add(animationGroup, forKey: "morph")

    //capture the frame of the animation.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(drawView.bounds.size, true, 0.0)
    drawView.drawHierarchy(in: drawView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    uiImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    uiImage = globalFunc.resizeUIImage(uiImage, scale, 400)
    cgImage = uiImage.cgImage!

    //add the captured image to movie file.
    movieCreator.create(image: cgImage)

    animationLayer.removeAnimation(forKey: "moprh")
}
```

This code doesn't work.

The image of each frame doesn't display and movie file is created but there's no animation.

I tried `DispatchQueue.main.asyc` and `CAtransition.begin(), .setCompletionBlock, .commit()` in the code above, but they didn't work.

What should I do to get what I want?

Comment: You shouldN#t use an animation. Instead modify the animated property with a timer loop (not just a simple for loop!). Use [`render(in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410909-render) to draw the layers content into an image context.

Comment: @macmoonshine Thank you for your answer! But I'm afraid that your way doesn't suite for my project. Because my animationGroup uses CAKeyframeAnimation so, it's too complex for animated property.
Anyway, thank you! BTW, why a simple for loop doesn't work?

Comment: CAAnimations are optimized for screen presentations. So, they have an uneven frame rate. Unfortunately, the framerate gets worse if you render the layers in between.

Comment: However, I have added an answer which should work with CAAnimations.

Answer (score 0):

You should not draw the view hierarchy into the image context. You should instead render the presentation layer like this:

```
if let presentationLayer = drawView.layer.presentation() {
    presentationLayer.render(in: context)
}
```

The presentation layer represents the layer's content which is currently drawn on the screen.

Comment: Thank you I tried your code but didn't work.
Each frame of the animation didn't display on screen and generated movie has no animation.

Comment: That sounds exactly like the problem which I described im my comment.

Comment: Hmm..., when capturing the animation, I run the animation for three times slower and kick `CADisplayLink` at 20fps to capture the image of each frame.
The way works fine on my iPhone6, but I think it's not smart way.
I want to generate the movie faster, when my app run on the faster device, that is why asked here.
Anyway, thank you for your advice!
Releasing my app, I'll be looking for other way for update.

Comment: Is `drawView` a container view? In this case you should try a layer of a sublayer which has animated content.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know whether my `drawView` is container view or not. `drawView` has `UIImage` which is background of animation. Without it, during a scale animation of the layer,  there's a gap between the transformed layer and `drawView` .

Comment: A container view doesn't draws own content. It only includes subviews.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! So, in my case `drawView` isn't a container view because it has UIImage. Is my understanding right?

Comment: Yes, how do you draw the image? Are you using a custom `drawRect`?

Comment: Yes, I use `drawRect` to render `UIImage` via `Context`. `drawView` displays the image. When animate the image, render it to `CALayer` then transform and rotate the layer. While the animation, drawView displays `UIImage` which filled a color as background.

Comment: Sorry, this is too much for solving in comments. Could you add a small example project?

Comment: Don't be sorry, thank you for your trying. Now, I want to concentrate to complete my app and release it. I have to create a lot of icons! I'll release it on December as early as I can. After that It is easy to show you what I want. It is lucky if you consult with me at that time!

Comment: It's been a long time since my last post. I released my first app in last December. Please download and try it! Of course, it's free. https://itunes.apple.com/jp/app/kist/id1320616182?l=en&mt=8